# Print command truncates message through sqlcmd on Linux

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

I am using sqlcmd on Linux (version 17.10.0001.1) to generate a SQL script that has a print statement. The sqlcmd is against Microsoft SQL Server 2017.

```
sqlcmd -S [server] -d [db] -U [user] -i input.sql -o output.sql
```

Inside input.sql:

```
[logic to generate @message]
PRINT @message
```

Size of the @message (NVARCHAR) is more than 1000 characters. But the PRINT statement only prints out about 1000 characters and then cuts off.

It only happens when I am using sqlcmd on Linux. When I use sqlcmd on Windows or on Mac, everything works. Does anybody have a clue why is it not working on linux?

Tried to cast the NVARCHAR to TEXT but it didn't do anything. Searched the internet for similar problems but didn't find anything. Can't use loops because the @message contains newlines and other logic that cannot be put into new lines at random.

Comment: I wouldn't trust print commands, they have max-cutoff etc. Have you tried SELECT @message? sqlcmd -h-1 -Q"SET NOCOUNT ON SELECT @message" -o file.sql

Comment: I previously tried but it truncated even more. Based on your comment I tried again. But this time I also learned about -y0 flag and it helped. Now it works. Thank you for your input.